# It is possible to track the text enter into nextline in UITextView iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uitextview, frame

Am working in UITextView for iPhone Messaging app. I have added an UIImage as a Subview on UITextView. I want to resize the UIImage frame size like UITextView frame height. Now I have coded for this but when the text entering into next line with few letters the image frame height not increasing. After we enter few more character the image frame size increasing.

```
    messageTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 5, 210, 30)];
    messageTextView.delegate = self;
    messageTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    messageTextView.clipsToBounds = NO;  
    messageTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];

    textViewImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 210, 30)];
    textViewImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"textbg.png"];
    textViewImageView.contentMode    = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    textViewImageView.contentStretch = CGRectMake(0.5, 0.5, 0, 0);

    [messageTextView addSubview: textViewImageView];
    [messageTextView sendSubviewToBack: textViewImageView];
    [messageTextView addSubview:textViewLabel];
    [self.view addSubview:messageTextView];


-(BOOL) textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
        CGRect frame = messageTextView.frame;
        frame.size.height = messageTextView.contentSize.height;

        messageTextView.frame = CGRectMake(35, 5, 210, frame.size.height);
        textViewImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 210, frame.size.height);
}
```

Could you please anyone help to solve the problem to increase the height of UIImageview height when the text enters into next line? Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How can you add a subview to UITextView?

Comment: @luyuan Ok it is any way to track the text enters into next line in UITextView? Please help me.

Comment: Your code seems ok, as the both frames have the same height. But why not try to add the messageTextView and textViewImageView to the same view and set exactly the same frame to them?

Comment: when the user enters text and the text reach the end of the width some letters goes to bottom on that time imageview frame height is less and the text show outside of the image. Can you please help me? Is there any way to break the text to nextline if the text reach end of the textview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

change

```
 [messageTextView addSubview: textViewImageView];

 textViewImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 210, 30)];

 textViewImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 210, frame.size.height);
```

into

```
 [messageTextView.superview addSubview: textViewImageView];

 textViewImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectMake(35, 5, 210, 30)];

 textViewImageView.frame = CGRectMake(35, 5, 210, frame.size.height);
```

As I tested just now, it works fine.

**Edit 2** In my test.

**TestViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>{

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;


@end
```

**TestViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.textView.delegate = self;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(BOOL) textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    CGRect frame = self.textView.frame;
    frame.size.height = self.textView.contentSize.height;

    self.textView.frame = frame;
    self.imageView.frame = frame;

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: When i added your code the textview look like this. Please see my question. I will upload another one image with the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Am facing the second image issue in my app. Could you please give some guide line to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: @Gopinath I upload an screen shot in my answer. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes i want like that. When a long text reach to the edge of UITextview on that time i'm facing the problem. If you don't mind could you please edit my question with your answer. So that i can find it easily. Sorry for the disturbance. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I will incorporate your thoughts and let you know the solution. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Lu yuan. Thanks for your helping hand. I have fixed the issue.

Comment: @Gopinath Congratulations. How did you fix it?